# nestjs websocket emitWithAck (nestjs emit acknowledgment)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

Has anyone used the emitWithAck method in nestjs? How to use it?
This is my code to use emitWithAck

```
emitWithAck(SocketEvents.EVENT_REMINDER_NEW, data , function (err: any, data: any) {
           console.log(data)
           console.log(err)
         });
```

But when I emit an event, I get this error
"operation has timed out"

define ack callback in nestjs websocket emit and call ack from react client

Answer (score 0):

To handle acknowledgments, you need to define the acknowledgment callback function on the client side (for example, in React).

Here's how you can utilize `emitWithAck`:

In your NestJS server:

```js
@WebSocketGateway()
export class MyGateway {
  @WebSocketServer() server: Server;

  @SubscribeMessage(SocketEvents.EVENT_REMINDER_NEW)
  async handleReminderNew(
    @MessageBody() data: any,
    @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket,
  ): Promise<any> {
    return await this.processReminder(data); // Implement your reminder logic here
  }
}
```

The function `processReminder` is meant to manage your reminder logic. The acknowledgment function is automatically included as the third parameter within the `handleReminderNew` function.

For the client side (React):

```js
const handleReminder = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await socket.emitWithAck(
      SocketEvents.EVENT_REMINDER_NEW,
      data,
    );

    if (result) {
      console.log('Event acknowledged:', result);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error emitting event:', error);
  }
};
```

The `emitWithAck` method returns a Promise. When the server acknowledges the event, this Promise resolves with the acknowledgment data. However, if a timeout or error occurs, the Promise will reject.

Should you encounter the "operation has timed out" error, consider adjusting the timeout duration to match your application's requirements. You have the option to include an optional second argument with the `emitWithAck` function, specifying the timeout duration in milliseconds.